# Is it possible to display a keyboard map in terminal?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout

I'd like to be able to display a keyboard map in terminal including dead keys - is it possible?

I wonder if there's, say, `ncurses` app able to display the keyboard with mappings listed, possibly with dead keys accents. I know already how to find which layout and model I have enabled. If those are modular, like basic layout being one part and dead keys are another (e.g. specified in separate files), I'd be happy enough with getting them separate. I have virtually no knowledge on this sort of internals (which is kinda obvious).

Answer (score 0):

Using setxkbmap you can get some information in terminal such as the layout, rules, model, options, keycodes, symbols, etc.

For example on my machine typing `setxkbmap -print` outputs the following:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+gr:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

And typing `setxkbmap -query` outputs:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,gr
variant:    ,
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

Comment: I know and that's unfortunately not my point - I wonder if there's, say, `ncurses` app able to display the keyboard with mappings listed, possibly with dead keys accents. I know already how to find which layout and model I have enabled. If those are modular, like basic layout being one part and dead keys are another (e.g. specified in separate files), I'd be happy enough with getting them separate. I have virtually no knowledge on this sort of internals (which is kinda obvious).

Comment: @moon.musick could you add that in your question?